# angularjs es6 lazy loading

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, lazy-loading

I have angularjs application, built with webpack.
I use ES6 modules, and import the css within each component.
Anyway, I want the CSS to be included and used only when I navigate to the component - lazy loading.
How can I do it?

Comment: JavaScript has `document.createElement('link')` function, you can resolve main logic for lazy-loading in your `angular.config`. Try to follow [this example](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-dynamically-injecting-css-file-using-route-resolve-and-promises-7bfcb8ccd05b)